# The natural ways to say you cannot remember something at the time being

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Suppose you are going to indicate that you are not able to remember a specific name, thing, address etc. at the time being; which one of the following self-made sentences doesn't sound natural to you:

> - I can’t remember it right now.
> - I can’t recall it right now.
> - It’s not coming to my mind right now.
> - It doesn’t come back to my mind right now.

For me, just the last two sentences sound a bit odd.
As far as I've heard, the verb "come to mind" refers to your 'own' mind only and consequently, the "one's" mind sounds a bit odd / redundant. Meanwhile, using 'back' seems to be something translated from another language, while to my experience, natives tend to use this structure without it. "Come to mind" and "come to me" are the expression which would work better here.

Comment: @Max :)) Alright. As far as I've heard, the verb "come to mind" refers to your 'own' mind only and consequently, the "one's" mind sounds a bit odd / redundant. Meanwhile, using 'back' seems to be something translated from another language, while to my experience, natives tend to use this structure without it. "Come to mind" and "come to me" are the expression which would work better here. This was all I knew. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your first three sentences

> I can’t remember right now.
>   I can’t recall right now.
>   It’s not coming to mind right now.

"it" and "my" are not necessary since they are implied.

> It doesn’t come back to my mind right now.

sounds overly learned as if coming from an English learner, better might be

> It doesn’t come to mind right now.

Comment: Thank you for being of help Peter. Just to make sure, could you please explain me why did you omit the pronoun 'it' in my first two sentences? :)

Answer (score -3):

`-It doesn’t come back to my mind right now.`
`-It’s not coming to my mind right now.`
This because, it seems a bit inconvenient and inappropriate way. Too long to say it seems like the thoughts are supposed to come walking. isn't it?

Comment: Generally, answers should also include explanations about why something is wrong or right.

Comment: updated the answer